# Error while installing stellar core

Tags: stellar-core

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://labs.imaginea.com/post/stellar-bc-wallet/) in order to build a private stellar network.

And I am still trying to install stellar-core.
When I run `./configure`, this is the error I get:

```
./configure: line 17739: syntax error near unexpected token libsodium,'
./configure: line 17739: PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libsodium, libsodium >= 1.0.13, :, libsodium_INTERNAL=yes)'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it? I made sure that I upgraded my gcc compiler to version 6 but I'm still struggling with the installation.

Comment: Full required toolchain is documented at https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL.md#adding-the-test-toolchain - try if that already fixes it. (Btw: there are also debian packages or docker images available, you don't neccessarily need to compile it on your own)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while I'm attempting a build on OSX (10.13.6), having installed all the listed dependencies at https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL.md#OSX.

I got the same error as previous post:

```
./configure: line 17696: syntax error near unexpected token 'libsodium,'
./configure: line 17696: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libsodium, libsodium >= 1.0.13, :, libsodium_INTERNAL=yes)'
```

Commenting out the referenced line of the configure script causes it to get to here:

```
./configure: line 17728: syntax error near unexpected token 'libsodium,'
./configure: line 17728: '   PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libsodium, libsodium)'
```

Commenting out that line of the configure script causes it to get to here:

```
./configure: line 17772: syntax error near unexpected token 'xdrpp,'
./configure: line 17772: '   PKG_CHECK_MODULES(xdrpp, xdrpp)'
```

Then here:

```
./configure: line 17847: syntax error near unexpected token 'libmedida,'
./configure: line 17847: 'PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libmedida, libmedida)'
```

Then:

```
./configure: line 17876: syntax error near unexpected token 'libpq,'<br>
./configure: line 17876: 'PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libpq, libpq, have_postgres=1)'
```

Thinking this might be related to the suggestion on Github to get around configure errors by setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'`, I tried that as well, but no luck.

In short, configure seems to complain about the syntax every time `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is called. Having commented out all lines referred to above, `./configure` completes successfully, as does `make`, `make check`, and `make install`, and `stellar-core` appears to be running properly.

This is less an "answer" than a workaround, but I thought it might be helpful to document these findings.